# Package-based controller resolving in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, naming-conventions, convention-over-configur

I would like to know if it is possible to make Spring MVC work like Stripes when resolving controller classes.

Normally I can annotate a controller with a `@RequestMapping` in order to map it to its URL.

However my boss asked for a convention-over-configuration mechanism derived from Stripes, which we are progressively abandoning after years of employment.

You see, Stripes `Actions` are scanned in classpath under packages that contain `stripes.action` in their name. Each subpackage is a virtual directory and ultimately a class named `SomethingAction` will map to url `Something.action`.

Whan I need to do is as follows:

`com.example.product.web.controllers.secure.admin.UserController` mapping to `/secure/admin/user`
`com.example.something.different.from.before.web.controllers.pub.WelcomeController mapping` to `/pub/welcome`

Basically I'd like to make Spring MVC automagically map controllers according to their full class name instead of using `@RequestMapping` on every controller.

**Important!** I don't need exactly *that* naming convention (`web.controllers`) if Spring MVC has already a naming convention. I simply need one.

I have found no clue so far.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html#setBasePackage-java.lang.String-) does it out-of-box what you are looking forward to.

Simply set the base package as `com.example.product.web.controllers` and the sub-packages would be mapped as *path* for you. To quote from API docs

> Specify a base package like "com.mycompany.myapp" to include subpackages within that base package as path elements, e.g. generating the path "/mymodule/buyform" for the class name "com.mycompany.myapp.mymodule.BuyForm". 
> Subpackage hierarchies are represented as individual path elements, e.g. "/mymodule/mysubmodule/buyform" for the class name "com.mycompany.myapp.mymodule.mysubmodule.BuyForm".

Do note that it is constrained to have only single *base package*. Incase there are different package hierarchies to scan, the behaviour of `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` has to be customized accordingly.